# getting started with javacc and using cmd

Tags: cmd, javacc

I'm trying to get srated with JavaCC using this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076269/learn-java/build-your-own-languages-with-javacc.html   tutorial. I'm not sure where to save the .jj file and how to run this file with javacc in command prompt. I've tried using `java -cp C:\javacc-5.0\bin\lib\javacc.jar javacc`  in cmd but it doesnt work.
Does anyone know how to start running javaCC for Windows?

Comment: Can you expand "it doesnt work"? What did you get, an error message?

Answer (score 1):

**If you have already edited your path environment variable for javacc, then you dont need to go ahead reading this answer and if you didn't the following should do the trick.**

You need to add javacc.jar to your path environment variable which can be done as follows.

1. Open cmd in administrator mode.
2. Type the following and enter

   **C:\Users\YourName> echo %PATH%**
3. Add the path to javacc using the setx command. For example,

   **C:\Users\YourName> setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\javacc-6.0\bin\lib\"**

If the command is successful you will find the following confirmation.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.

Now, you can 'cd' into the directory of your .jj file and execute the command you've tried and it should work fine.

Comment: Instead of "the command you've tried", perhaps they should try "javacc file.jj".